# connection between Android Studio and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, android-studio, pgadmin

I've just started to learn Android Studio. I created the database on PgAdmin but I can't connect Android Studio and PostgreSQL. How can I connect Android Studio and PostgreSQL?

Comment: Did you already check [Cant connect my Android Studio App with PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084439/cant-connect-my-android-studio-app-with-postgresql) ? If not, maybe explain how far you came on the studio side? How do you connect with other databases or details like this might help. Thanks.